# slack chat_postMessage works but client.files_upload_v2 not able to upload file to channel

Tags: python-3.x, slack

The client.files_upload_v2 command runs without throwing an error, but the file does not appear in the channel.

If i check response['ok'], I get true.

If I check: response['files'][0]['url_private'] I get a link where I can download the file, so it DOES seems to be uploading to slack, but, unfortunately, the file doesn't appear in the channel.

```
from slack_sdk import WebClient

def upload_file_to_slack2(ch, a_file, comment):
    token = "xoxp-3599...    "
    ch = "XXXXXXXXXX"
    client = WebClient(token)
    response = client.chat_postMessage(channel=ch, text='testing postMessage from python!') # this runs fine - text appears in channel
    response = client.files_upload_v2( channel=ch,title=a_file,file=a_file)  # runs without throwing error but file doesn't appear in the channel
```

```
print("Channels:",response['files'][0]['channels'])
```

produces:  Channels: []

I'm suspicious that this has to do with either a missing scope or issues with OAuth. In the docs it says the OAuth changed for bot tokens but doesn't say when.

I have been using a user token, but should I instead use a bot token if I'm the only user?

I have:
chat:write,  files:read, and files:write as scopes for both my bot and user token.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: uploading the file, get the permlink from response,  then post the permalink to the same channel and the file then shows up.

```
response = client.files_upload_v2( channel=ch,title=a_file,file=a_file)
permalink = response['files'][0]['permalink']
response = client.chat_postMessage(channel=ch, text=permalink)
```

I thought this was the behavior that was fixed by files_upload_V2.